# glmer vs lmer, what is best for a binomial outcome?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I am trying to fit a mixed effects model with a binary outcome. I have one fixed effect (Offset) and one random effect (chamber, with muliple data points coming from each chamber).

In the text book "The R Book", (2007), pg 604, Crawley suggests using the lmer function with a binomial family for the analysis of binomial data where each participant contributes multiple responses (analagous to each of my chambers contributing multiple outcomes). Based on this example, I have used the following script for my data:

```
    ball=lmer(Buried~Offset+(1|Chamber), family=binomial, data=ballData)
```

When I run this model, I get this warning:

```
    calling lmer with 'family' is deprecated; please use glmer() instead
```

When I change my code to the following, the model works:

```
    ball=glmer(Buried~Offset+(1|Chamber), family=binomial, data=ballData)
```

Based on other questions/answers that I have read on Cross Validated, lmer should only be used for data where the outcome is normally distributed, and glmer is the correct function to use for a binomial outcome. My questions are:

1) Could anyone clarify the discrepency between Crawleys advice and the fact that lmer would not work for me (nor, based on what I have read on CVed, is it recommended to use this function for binomial data)

2) Is glmer indeed the correct function to use to model a binomial outcome with random factors?

3) Assuming that glmer is the correct function to use, I want to compare a model with and without random effects to determine if including random effects improves the fit of the model. I understand that glmer estimates model parameters via maximum likelihood. What function can I use to create a model with no random effects for a binary outcome using maximum likelihood? I was playing around with glm however the help file for this function states that the method of estimation is iteratively reweighted least squares (which is beyond me, but it isn't ML...)

Comment: A minor point, but one which I believe is not presently addressed by any of the answers: while `lmer` is no longer appropriate to use with binary outcomes, it is not the case that "lmer should only be used for data where the outcome is normally distributed". More information on this issue is available [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/217828/9162).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) In previous versions of the `lme4` package, you could run `lmer` using the `binomial` family. However, all this did was to actually call `glmer`, and this functionality has now been removed. So at the time of writing Crawley was correct.

2) Yes, `glmer` is the correct function to use with a binary outcome.

3) `glm` can fit a model for binary data without random effects. However, it is incorrect to compare a model fitted with `glm` to one fitted with `glmer` using a likelihood-based test because the likelihoods are not comparable. From your description, you have repeated measures within chambers. So, assuming that you have sufficient chambers and these can be thought of as a random sample from a larger population of chambers, then *a priori* you should retain the random intercepts for `Chamber` to control for possible non-independence of observations within chambers. You can think of random intercepts as being part of the experimental design.

On the other hand, if the random effect variance is very small and/or the inference or predictions for both the `glm` and `glmer` model are the largely the same, then it really doesn't matter which you use anyway.

Comment: actually, I think the likelihoods are comparable now between `glm` and `lmer` - but I think your advice to keep the random effect is correct anyway

Comment: Thank you Robert for your advice. Im not too interested in the random effects, I just want to control for the non independence of the responses that came from the same chamber. The variance associated with the random intercepts (grouped by chamber) are quite small, and the models with and without the random terms give me the same answer for my fixed effect. But I will keep the random intercepts to control for the non indepence of the data. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

For 2, yes, you should use glmer or glm for binomial outcomes. If you have a little more time to wait for the model to fit---and especially if you are interested in inference for your random effects---I'd suggest using `rstanarm::stan_glmer()` and `rstanarm::stan_glm` respectively, which use the same syntax. The huge benefit here is that your uncertainty estimates come from a genuine posterior. Your predictions will also include uncertainty from the parameters. A tip though: make sure you scale your data to be in the single digits.

Be warned that the posterior density of random effects tend to be skewed, so using likelihood-based methods (as in lme4) will tend to give you bad random effect estimates.

3) The `loo` package allows comparison of your `stan_` fits using an approximation to leave-one-out cross validation. I recommend taking a look.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/vignettes/glmer.html

Comment: hmm. could you expand on (1) "make sure you scale your data to be in the single digits" (what problems would this cause `rstanarm`?) and (2) "using likelihood-based methods (as in lme4) will tend to give you bad random effect estimates" ?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Jim. Im quite new to r, and I did get a little lost in your answer. Could you clarify what the rstanarm::stan function does?

Comment: Ben - varying intercept/slope models tend to have some crazy looking likelihoods if you have numbers with different orders of magnitude. So it can be helpful to scale - say, within -10 and 10.

Comment: JeanDrayton: the `rstanarm` package implements the same models in `lme4`, but estimates them using Bayesian techniques. For varying-intercept/slope models, the main advantage is that you get better estimates of the varying intercepts and slopes. To use them, simply download `rstanarm` and then replace your call to `glmer()` with `stan_glmer()`, and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi @Jim, your answer to this post is very interesting. Just a question, is it possible to relate the resulting parameters that you get from a lmer , let’s say from a treatment response model and kind of associate this to another binary data like yes or no ? I couldn’t find literature that help me with this. Thanks.