# ANOVA for 5-likert scale comparing 3-4 groups?

Tags: r, anova, variance, likert

I have to compare the answers of 3 or 4 different groups (this depends on each question). The questions asked are asking the participants to fill in a 5-likert scale (totally disagree, disagree, not disagree nor agree, agree and totally agree).

Can I use ANOVA for this? And how do I do this in R?

Answer (score 3):

Use of Anova with Likert scales is problematic as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10/under-what-conditions-should-likert-scales-be-used-as-ordinal-or-interval-data?rq=1) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175848/parametric-tests-and-likert-scales-ordinal-data-two-different-views).

My recommendation is to use [ordered logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) or some other model from [Item response theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory). In R you can use `polr` function from [MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/) package ([here](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/) is a nice tutorial) or use MCMC samplers such as [rSTAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/index.html) or [rJAGS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjags/index.html) for more flexibility.